# Strategy Tester Overview Data Extract

Tags: strategy-pattern, pine-script

I was wondering if anybody knows if the values in the Strategy Testing tab, under Overview:

1. List item
2. Net Profit
3. Total Closed Trades
4. Percent Profitable
5. Profit Factor
6. Max Drawdown
7. Avg Trade
8. Avg # Bars in Trade

Are stored in variables somewhere in pine script to be utilized for further analysis and comparison?

Answer (score 0):

Some of them are available as `strategy.*` variables which you will find in the [refman](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/). The others need to be calculated as is done in this script: [Backtesting & Trading Engine [PineCoders]](https://www.tradingview.com/script/dYqL95JB-Backtesting-Trading-Engine-PineCoders/).